# How to Start Graphical Neovim from OS X Terminal?

Tags: neovim, macos

I have installed the terminal neovim which starts by `nvim`, and the graphical neovim. 
I cannot find the keybinding to start the graphical neovim in Terminal.

I installed the neovim by following instructions in Github [here](https://github.com/neovim/homebrew-neovim/blob/master/README.md), by Homebrew; still checking if it install also the graphical one which I have also

```
brew install neovim/neovim/neovim
```

My Graphical Neovim is NVIM 0.1.3 which homepage is [here](https://neovim.io/).

---

How can you start Neovim from Terminal?

Comment: What do you mean by "graphical Neovim in Terminal"? Is there some feature in a GUI version of Neovim that you're lacking in terminal version?

Comment: What graphical neovim did you install? How? Did you read its documentation?

Comment: You probably installed [Neovim.app](https://github.com/rogual/neovim-dot-app), which can be started as `gnvim`.

Comment: Your Graphical Neovim can't be NVIM because NVIM doesn't ship with a GUI, @Masi.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a nice implementation of NeoVim GUI for macOS named [VimR](http://vimr.org) (R = Refined). It has a native file manager and works fine and fast with mouse gestures and macOS UI. VimR comes with a command line tool `vimr`. VimR [repository](https://github.com/qvacua/vimr) is more active and has more stars comparing to [neovim-dot-app](https://github.com/rogual/neovim-dot-app).
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the only NeoVim GUI for Mac OS X at the moment is [Neovim.app](https://github.com/rogual/neovim-dot-app). It installs a script called `gnvim` which behaves just like good old `gvim`, starting a GUI version and accepting all the parameters (but see 'vim_diff.txt' for details on changed, missing and removed features.)